# SEO and Angular Translation using ngx-translate

Tags: angular, seo, angular-routing, ngx-translate, angular-seo

I'm wondering how SEO is working for translated webpages from Angular app. I can see sometimes that when the translate call makes few time to retrieve the translation, the translation code are displayed before being translated. Does Google and other search engine are indexing on the translated content, or on the translation codes using ngx-translate ?

I'm wondering the same about descriptions and titles. As I'm using routing data to update them, does the SEO takes the final title and description or there is a risk that it's not going to use the correct values ?